# How do I produce a plot in SAS with variable names on one axis?

Tags: graph, sas

I have a data set with the following variables: student ID, OS, RAM, browser, Step1, Step2, Step3, Step4, Step5, Step6, Step7, etc. The step variables contain numeric values representing times, while the other variables are categorical. I've already used proc means to produce tables showing the mean values for each step both overall and when broken down by various categories. The code looks like this:

```
proc means data=times;
    var step1 step2 step3 step4 step5 step6 step7;
    output out=means mean=mean;
run;

proc means data=times;
    var step1 step2 step3 step4 step5 step6 step7;
    class status;
    output out=means mean=mean;
run;

proc means data=times;
    var step1 step2 step3 step4 step5 step6 step7;
    class Experience_in_SAS;
    output out=means mean=mean;
run;

proc means data=times;
    var step1 step2 step3 step4 step5 step6 step7;
    class OS_cleaned;
    output out=means mean=mean;
run;

proc means data=times;
    var step1 step2 step3 step4 step5 step6 step7;
    class RAM_GB;
    output out=means mean=mean;
run;

proc means data=times;
    var step1 step2 step3 step4 step5 step6 step7;
    class browser;
    output out=means mean=mean;
run;
```

What I would like to do is produce plots with the Steps on the x-axis and means (or perhaps boxplots) on the y-axis, so that I can graphically see how values vary across steps. I would also like to do something similar to compare step values across different OSs or browsers, for example, still with steps on the x-axis and with one line for each OS, but I haven't been able to figure out how to do this.

How should I go about producing these plots?

[here's some image of the output I have so far if that helps to clarify the issue](https://i.stack.imgur.com/iNeWf.png)

[Here's what some of the original data looks like](https://i.stack.imgur.com/olOXj.png)

[Here's an example of what a graph might look like, with step number on the x-axis and average value for that step on the y-axis. The graphs broken down by category might have grouped bars instead.](https://i.stack.imgur.com/eHHBl.png)

To clarify: the main problem is that I want to get the variable/column names into the x-axis.

Comment: `Proc SGPLOT`  and either `VBOX` or `HBOX` statement.  Add sample data to the question tried code and image of desired plot (hand drawn even)

Comment: Thanks for the help! I've edited the post.